# Where is the h function of the exponential family gone?

Tags: classification, linear-model, exponential-family, scale-invariance

The problem comes from equation (4.86) of text "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" written by Christopher M. Bishop $$a_k({\bf x})={\bf\lambda}_k^T{\bf x}+\ln g({\bf\lambda}_k)+\ln p(\mathcal C_k).$$

This equation is obtained by substituting the class-conditional density of the exponential family with scale invariance (4.84)
$$p({\bf x}|{\bf\lambda}_k,s)=\frac{1}{s}h\left(\frac{1}{s}{\bf x}\right)g({\bf\lambda}_k)\exp\left\{\frac{1}{s}{\bf\lambda}_k^T{\bf x}\right\}$$
into (4.63)
$$a_k=\ln p({\bf x}|\mathcal C_k)p(\mathcal C_k)$$
to show that it is a general linear model.

But where is $h\left(\frac{1}{s}{\bf x}\right)$ gone after taking logarithm?